# Подскажите, где ошибка в шаблоне, С++

Tags: c++, ооп, c++11, шаблоны-с++, c++14

Здравствуйте, я написал шаблон вот таким образом.
CompositeShape.hpp

```
class CompositeShape : public Shape
{
public:

  CompositeShape();
  ~CompositeShape();

  template<class T>
  void addComponent(T shape);
  void removeComponent(const int index = -1); //  if don't input index, then method will remove last component
  virtual void move(const point_t &posTo) override;
  virtual void move(const double dx, const double dy) override;
  virtual void scale(const double coefficient);
  virtual double getArea() const;
  rectangle_t getFrameRect() const;
  int getLength() const;
  virtual void print(std::string name) const;
private:
  int maxlength_;
  int length_;
  Shape **shapes_;
  void setPosition();

};
```

А описан он в CompositeShape.spp

```
#include "CompositeShape.hpp"


CompositeShape::CompositeShape() :
  Shape({0,0}),
  maxlength_(5),
  length_(0)
{
  shapes_ = new Shape *[maxlength_];
}

CompositeShape::~CompositeShape()
{
  delete[] shapes_;
}

void CompositeShape::removeComponent(const int index)
{
  //TODO:FIXME
  if (length_ <= 0) {
    //TODO: message about exception
    return;
  }
  if (index == -1 && length_ > 0) {
     shapes_[--length_] = nullptr;
     if (length_ > 0) {
      setPosition();
     }
  }
  if (index < length_ && index >= 0 && length_ > 0) {
    shapes_[index] = nullptr;
    for (int i = index; i < length_ - 1; i++) {
      shapes_[i] = shapes_[i + 1];
    }
    shapes_[--length_] = nullptr;
    if (length_ > 0) {
      setPosition();
    }

  } else {
    // TODO: massege about exception
    }
 }
 void CompositeShape::move(const point_t &posTo)
 {
    if (length_ <= 0) {
       //TODO: massage about exception
        return;
     }
      setPosition();

      move(posTo.x - position_.x, posTo.y - position_.y);
  }
   void CompositeShape::move(const double dx, const double dy)
   {
      if (length_ <= 0) {
      //TODO: massage about exception
      return;
   }
   setPosition();
   position_.x += dx;
   position_.y += dy;
   //FIXME:
   for (int i = 0; i < length_; i++) {
      shapes_[i]->move(dx, dy);
   }
}
void CompositeShape::scale(const double coefficient)
{
  if (length_ <= 0) {
    //TODO: massage about exception
    return;
 }
  setPosition();
  for (int i = 0; i < length_; i++) {
    shapes_[i]->move({position_.x + coefficient * (shapes_[i]->getPosition().x - position_.x),
                  position_.y + coefficient * (shapes_[i]->getPosition().y - position_.y)});//FIXME:
     shapes_[i]->scale(coefficient);
  }
 }
 double CompositeShape::getArea() const
 {
   if (length_ <= 0) {
     //TODO: massage about exception
      return -1;
   }

   double area = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < length_; i++) {
      area += shapes_[i]->getArea();
   }
  return area;
 }
 rectangle_t CompositeShape::getFrameRect() const
 {
   if (length_ <= 0) {
    //TODO: massage about exception
      return {{0, 0}, -1, -1};
   }
   double left = shapes_[0]->getPosition().x - shapes_[0]->getFrameRect().width / 2;
   double right = shapes_[0]->getPosition().x + shapes_[0]->getFrameRect().width / 2;
    double top = shapes_[0]->getPosition().y + shapes_[0]->getFrameRect().height / 2;
   double bottom = shapes_[0]->getPosition().y - shapes_[0]->getFrameRect().height / 2;
   for (int i = 1; i < length_; i++) {
       if ((shapes_[i]->getPosition().x - shapes_[i]->getFrameRect().width / 2) < left) {
       left = shapes_[i]->getPosition().x - shapes_[i]->getFrameRect().width / 2;
      }
     if ((shapes_[i]->getPosition().x + shapes_[i]->getFrameRect().width / 2) > right) {
       right = shapes_[i]->getPosition().x + shapes_[i]->getFrameRect().width / 2;
     }
     if ((shapes_[i]->getPosition().y + shapes_[i]->getFrameRect().height / 2) > top) {
      top = shapes_[i]->getPosition().y + shapes_[i]->getFrameRect().height / 2;
      }
     if ((shapes_[i]->getPosition().y - shapes_[i]->getFrameRect().height / 2) < bottom) {
       bottom = shapes_[i]->getPosition().y - shapes_[i]->getFrameRect().height / 2;
      }
   }
   return {{(left + (right - left) / 2), (bottom + (top - bottom) / 2)}, (right - left), (top - bottom)};
 }

 void CompositeShape::setPosition()
  {
   if (length_ > 0) {
     position_ = getFrameRect().pos;
   }
 }
 int CompositeShape::getLength() const
 {
   return length_;
 }
 void CompositeShape::print(std::string name) const
 {
   std::cout << name << std::endl;
   for (int i = 0; i < length_; i++) {
    shapes_[i]->print("from composite shape");
  }

 }
  template <class T>
  void CompositeShape::addComponent(T shape) {
   //TODO:FIXME
   if (std::is_base_of<Shape,T>::value){
     std::cout << "Exception: can add not Shape element" << std::endl;
     return;
   }

   if (length_ < maxlength_) {

     Shape *shape1 = new T(shape);

     shapes_[length_] = shape1;
     length_++;

      setPosition();

    } else {
      Shape **shapes1 = shapes_;
      shapes_ = new Shape *[maxlength_ + 5];
      for (int i = 0; i < maxlength_; i++) {
         shapes_[i] = shapes1[i];
      }
      delete[] shapes1;
      maxlength_ += 5;
      addComponent(shape);
   }

 }
```

При этом если написать такой год в `main`

```
 #include "CompositeShape.hpp"
 # include "rectangle.hpp"
 Rectangle rect1 = Rectangle({0, 0}, 10, 10);
```

то получим ошибку

```
 CompositeShape compositeShape;
 compositeShape.addComponent(rect1);
      undefined reference to void CompositeShape::add 
       component <Rectangle>(Rectangle)
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Подправил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя реализации шаблонов выносить в файлы .cpp.

Вот это -

```
template <class T>
  void CompositeShape::addComponent(T shape) {
...
```

перенесите в `CompositeShape.hpp`.

Подумайте сами, встав на место компилятора - для какого типа `T` компилятор должен инстанцировать этот шаблон, чтоб закатать его в объектный файл в виде вызываемой функции? Если вызывается он где-то совсем в другом месте?

Второй вариант - заставить инстанцировать шаблон с тем типом, о котором **знаете вы**, но не компилятор - он о нем узнает при компиляции файла с `main()`. Но это нехорошее решение - если у вас что-то изменится, добавится новый тип или что еще - вы получите ту же проблему. Так что просто все реализации шаблонов пишите во включаемых файлах...